# connecting eclipse with tomcat - version issue

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I have installed Java EE Eclipse Kepler and I have Apache Tomcat v9.0.2 installed. when I want to connect tomcat v9.0.2 to eclipse, I only see Tomcat v3.2 up tp v7.0 Server in the new server window. How can I get Tomcat V.9 displayed in the wizard window?

Answer (score 0):

> Hi You need to use new Eclipse like Oxygen or Neon for using Tomcat 9. Old
>   Eclipse version's like Kepler won't support Tomcat 9. Instead you can
>   use Tomcat 6 or 7 for Kepler.

I am using Eclipse Oxygen, So i can see Tomcat 9. Check my eclipse below.

[image: my eclipse]